# Plugin for vscode

Tags: sorbet

I am trying to test Sorbet on a Rails project.

- followed the adoptions guidelines
- installed and run the `gem sorbet-rails`
- changed to `# typed: true`
- restarted vscode

but nothing is really happening, I think I am missing a part of the puzzle.
Has anyone found a solution to get Sorbet to work with Vs Code

Thanks

Comment: You're missing the plugin part, I think

Comment: but it should still work in command line

Comment: yeah I suppose but where can I find the plugin looking at the vscode market place returns nothing 

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=sorbet&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

Comment: Sorbet was released two days ago. Give plugin authors some time, it'll come :)

Comment: sure thanks was just wondering if I missed something from the doc or not

Answer (score 2):

Sorbet committer here.
VSCode plugin is currently going through stabilization of features at Stripe.
It will be open-sourced when it is feature complete and stable.

You can see a preview of how it will work at [the demo site](https://sorbet.run).

Comment: Hi. Any updates on availability of VSCode plugin for Sorbet?

Comment: Why don't you just release it? There are other companies using Sorbet, we could all help in developing it, even if it is currently unstable.

Comment: It would be SO helpful to have access to the plugin. Can't wait for you guys to release it